# Use specific version of library

Tags: c, linux

I have a Linux program written in C with a statically linked library. The version of the library_x is e.g. 1.0.1.

When just my program is called on a PC my library_x version 1.0.1 is loaded and it works like expected.

But when on the PC the calling program has already "loaded" another version of library_x, e.g. 1.0.0, my library_x 1.0.1 is not loaded anymore. In the stack I can see that calls of my code are directed to library_x 1.0.0.

Can this be avoided? How can force that my library_x 1.0.1 is used by my code?

Comment: This shouldn't happen if the library is linked statically.

Comment: It seems that your linked hardcoded library version (usually it hardcode also fallback versions, aka 1.0 and 1.

Comment: Please show us how you compiled and linked your program.

Comment: To resolve your question, we would need to know 1. What is the exact filename of your library, and in which exact folder is this library located. 2. The exact command you ran to create your executable (and link it to your library). 3. The output you get when you run `ldd ./yourexecutable` both on the PC where it is working and the PC where it is not working. 4. The exact location of the your version 1.0.1 library on the PC where it is not woking, and the location of the version 1.0.0 library on that same PC. Note, what you describe should not happen when you link statically

Comment: Do you mean dynamically linked?

Comment: Do you mean dynamically linked? If so, and you need to be "absolutely certain" of which library is being used, you may want to do the run-time linking yourself, and consider using the dlopen() family of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem. What I did is quite simple and done without any specials. To reproduce I put you all the details here below.

If you need some basic information you should check out this page:
http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries/

Full example:

Makefile:

```
all: go1 go2

mylib.so.1: mylib.so.1.1.1
    ln -s mylib.so.1.1.1 mylib.so.1

mylib.so.2: mylib.so.2.2.2
    ln -s mylib.so.2.2.2 mylib.so.2

go1: main.cpp mylib.so.1.1.1 mylib.so.1
    $(CXX) -O3  mylib.so.1.1.1 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra main.cpp -g -o go1

go2: main.cpp mylib.so.2.2.2 mylib.so.2
    $(CXX) -O3 mylib.so.2.2.2 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra main.cpp -g -o go2

mylib.so.1.1.1: lib1.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -Wl,-soname,mylib.so.1 -o mylib.so.1.1.1 -shared lib1.cpp

mylib.so.2.2.2: lib2.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -Wl,-soname,mylib.so.2 -o mylib.so.2.2.2 -shared lib2.cpp

clean:
    rm -f go*
    rm -f main.o f1.o f2.o
    rm -f mylib*.so.*
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <unistd.h>
void f1();

int main()
{   
    sleep(2);
    f1();
}
```

lib1.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
void f1() { std::cout << "Version 1 " << std::endl; }
```

lib2.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
void f1() { std::cout << "Version 2 " << std::endl; }
```

You can call it by:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
>
> go1 & go2

As you can see both versions run in parallel and using different versions of the shared library. So I simply can not reproduce your problem!

Comment: Thanks for valuable feedback and to let me know that it must work. With the example code I cannot reproduce it, too. So I´m checking my compile and link settings to find the root cause.